# Select last table or table row on page to parse using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am scraping (baseball) player game logs/stats each day. The player page has a different table for each month, but they all have the same ID/labels in the HTML code. Current code below finds all tables and then cycles through them to find the row with today's date to grab the one new line of data. How can it be changed to skip to the last table row on the page and read that into `todaystats` when the date is equal to `date_today`? Or, at least, skip to the last table on the page before it starts cycling through the rows to find the one with today's date?

```
tables = urllib.request.urlopen(URL).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(tables, 'html.parser')
tables = soup.find_all('table')
dfpitcher = pd.read_html(str(tables), flavor="bs4")
for i, df in enumerate(dfpitcher):
     df.columns = ['Date', 'Opponent', 'ERA', 'Result', 'PA', 'IP', 'H', 'HR', 'BB', 'HBP', 'K', 'R', 'ER', 'OAVG']
     todaystats = df.loc[df['Date'] == date_today]
```

Comment: It would help if you showed us what you are actually scraping... (Ie what's your `URL` )

Comment: Give us more info

Comment: Sure.. a sample URL is at: http://eng.koreabaseball.com/Teams/PlayerInfoHitter/GameLogs.aspx?pcode=50923

Answer (score 0):

This script will find row which corresponds to current date. If no row is found, it prints error message:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime


url = 'http://eng.koreabaseball.com/Teams/PlayerInfoHitter/GameLogs.aspx?pcode=50923'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
date_now = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%m.%d')

row = soup.select_one('tr:has(td:contains("{}"))'.format(date_now))
if row:
    tds = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in row.select('td')]
    print(*tds, sep='\t')
else:
    print('Row for current date {} not found!'.format(date_now))
```

Prints:

```
08.01   DOOSAN  0.667   3   1   2   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0
```

---

If you want to print only last row:

```
row = soup.select('tr')[-1]
tds = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in row.select('td')]
print(*tds, sep='\t')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use pandas to grab the last table, then match on the date:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

date_today = float(datetime.today().strftime('%m.%d'))

url = 'http://eng.koreabaseball.com/Teams/PlayerInfoHitter/GameLogs.aspx?pcode=50923'
df = pd.read_html(url)[-1]
todaystats = df.loc[df.iloc[:,0] == date_today]
```